# How to use `hasmethod` (or any other way) to find if `hasmethod(fn, Tuple{Type1, Type2, **Any Type**})`

Tags: julia

I want to use the `hasmethod` function to find if an object `t::T` supports `t[!, something]` syntax.

The key is `something` can be of many types and I don't want to check them all, I just want a way to express that `hasmethod(getindex, Tuple{T, typeof{!}, S})` regardless of what `S` is.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to get the list of methods is:

```
methods(getindex, Tuple{Any, typeof(!), Any})
```

The only problem is that if the second argument allowed by `getindex` is a supertype of `typeof(!)` it will be also listed. I do not think it can be avoided though, as you cannot rule out that such `getindex` definition actually allows `!` to be passed as a first argument.

For instance if no packages are loaded the following is the result of the call above:

```
julia> methods(getindex, Tuple{Any, typeof(!), Any})
# 10 methods for generic function "getindex":
[1] getindex(md::Markdown.MD, args...) in Markdown at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Markdown\src\parse\parse.jl:24
[2] getindex(r::Distributed.Future, args...) in Distributed at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Distributed\src\remotecall.jl:624
[3] getindex(::Type{Any}, vals...) in Base at array.jl:357
[4] getindex(::Type{T}, x, y) where T in Base at array.jl:353
[5] getindex(::Type{T}, vals...) where T in Base at array.jl:344
[6] getindex(A::SparseArrays.SparseMatrixCSC, i, ::Colon) in SparseArrays at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\SparseArrays\src\sparsematrix.jl:1879
[7] getindex(A::AbstractArray, I...) in Base at abstractarray.jl:979
[8] getindex(t::AbstractDict, k1, k2, ks...) in Base at abstractdict.jl:476
[9] getindex(itr::Base.SkipMissing, I...) in Base at missing.jl:232
[10] getindex(r::Distributed.RemoteChannel, args...) in Distributed at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Distributed\src\remotecall.jl:626
```

All of the cases are the ones where `getindex` does not put restrictions on the second argument so you cannot rule out that they could possibly allow `!` as a valid value.

But if e.g. you load DataFrames.jl and restrict the first argument to `AbstractDataFrame` you get:

```
julia> methods(getindex, Tuple{AbstractDataFrame, typeof(!), Any})
# 5 methods for generic function "getindex":
[1] getindex(df::DataFrame, ::typeof(!), col_ind::Symbol) in DataFrames at D:\AppData\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:367
[2] getindex(df::DataFrame, ::typeof(!), col_ind::Union{Signed, Unsigned}) in DataFrames at D:\AppData\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:358

[3] getindex(df::DataFrame, row_ind::typeof(!), col_inds::Union{Colon, Regex, AbstractArray{T,1} where T, All, Between, InvertedIndex}) in DataFrames at D:\AppData\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:405
[4] getindex(sdf::SubDataFrame, ::typeof(!), colind::Union{Signed, Symbol, Unsigned}) in DataFrames at D:\AppData\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\subdataframe\subdataframe.jl:127
[5] getindex(df::SubDataFrame, row_ind::typeof(!), col_inds::Union{Colon, Regex, AbstractArray{T,1} where T, All, Between, InvertedIndex}) in DataFrames at D:\AppData\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\subdataframe\subdataframe.jl:137
```

which is now more informative, because in DataFrames.jl we try to be careful not to leave indexing arguments free (i.e. allow them to be `Any` and only internally check what is valid).

Additionally you can use `methodswith` to check which methods accept `!` explicitly and filter only `getindex` instances. Here is the result after loading DataFrames.jl:

```
julia> filter(x -> x.name == :getindex, methodswith(typeof(!)))
[1] getindex(df::DataFrame, ::typeof(!), col_ind::Symbol) in DataFrames at D:\AppData\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:367
[2] getindex(df::DataFrame, ::typeof(!), col_ind::Union{Signed, Unsigned}) in DataFrames at D:\AppData\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:358

[3] getindex(df::DataFrame, row_ind::typeof(!), col_inds::Union{Colon, Regex, AbstractArray{T,1} where T, All, Between, InvertedIndex}) in DataFrames at D:\AppData\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:405
[4] getindex(sdf::SubDataFrame, ::typeof(!), colind::Union{Signed, Symbol, Unsigned}) in DataFrames at D:\AppData\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\subdataframe\subdataframe.jl:127
[5] getindex(df::SubDataFrame, row_ind::typeof(!), col_inds::Union{Colon, Regex, AbstractArray{T,1} where T, All, Between, InvertedIndex}) in DataFrames at D:\AppData\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\subdataframe\subdataframe.jl:137
```

Finally note that `x[!, y]` syntax can also mean a `view` (if preceded by e.g. `@view`) or a `setindex!` operation (if it appears on LHS of assignment) so you might wan to check also these functions if they accept `!` (and in DataFrames.jl they actually do).

Comment: `methods(getindex, Tuple{T, typeof(!), Any})` as I know the type is `T`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in theory, if you get the syntax right:

```
julia> hasmethod(getindex, Tuple{Vector{Int}, typeof(!), Any})
true
```

This should work since `Tuple`s are covariant.

But its returning `true` is obviously nonsense:

```
julia> getindex([1], !, 1)
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid index: ! of type typeof(!)
Stacktrace:
 [1] to_index(::Function) at ./indices.jl:270
 [2] to_index(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Function) at ./indices.jl:247
 [3] to_indices(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, ::Tuple{typeof(!),Int64}) at ./indices.jl:298
 [4] to_indices at ./indices.jl:294 [inlined]
 [5] getindex(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Function, ::Int64) at ./abstractarray.jl:981
 [6] top-level scope at REPL[26]:1
```

The reason is that it delegates to [other methods](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/74f2de13727373b44da76a65ceb5297889d3e482/base/abstractarray.jl#L978) internally.

I think it's better to constrain `T` to some abstract type(s) for which this kind of indexing is known to work.  Or, as a last resort, use `try`.

Comment: I think your answer does not quite answer the question. For instance, consider `foo(x::Int, y::Float64, z::String) = "$x + $y"*" "*z`. If I do `hasmethod(foo, Tuple{Int, Float64, Any})` I get false. The OP wanted a way for this to work regardless of what the signature on the final argument is.

Comment: Oh yes, you're correct. I'll have a look on this tomorrow.